# What are the implications of submitting a paper to be graded and to arxiv preprint on the same day?

Tags: graduate-school, arxiv, grading, preprint

I submitted my paper to be graded in a university class and to the arvix preprint on the same day. Are there any implications for the grading professor and myself if the arxiv preprint is announced before I am graded?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik hopefully my edits make it clearer: a project paper and to the ARXIV preprint.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik graded for a class. I tagged graduate-school, sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I don't see any problem..

Comment: What kind of problem do you think about?

Comment: If it is a reasonable prof, no problem.

Comment: The only problem I can see is: why didn't the professor recommend that you submit the paper on arXiv? If he hasn't seen the paper yet (since the paper was just submitted for grading, it seems it is the case), did anyone proofread and check your article before you put it on arXiv?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there are no implications. Professors grading your work don’t care what you submit to arXiv, and the arXiv doesn’t care what you submit for grading. At any university I have ever had experience with, those two things would not affect each other in any way.

But what you did still doesn’t make sense to me. The only type of work that’s suitable for submitting to arXiv is a research paper. And I have never heard of a student submitting a research paper as a class project to be graded - it’s not that that’s not allowed or anything but research papers usually materialize as a result of extended effort that goes outside the scope of work done for a specific class. It would be a bit like submitting a class project that’s, say, five times longer and harder to write than the requirement. You would get an A, surely, but again, for obvious reasons that’s not something you ever see students doing.

(**Edit:** according to the comments, writing research papers for a class project is not uncommon in some disciplines, or at least may have not been uncommon several decades ago.)

My suspicion is you have some misconception about the benefits of submitting your class paper to arXiv. Perhaps you should rethink whether that’s something that you want to do and/or consult some experienced people about whether it makes sense. But regardless, for your actual question I don’t see any problems for you related specifically to the simultaneous submission to arXiv and to the professor.

Comment: Apart from the contents, I would find it odd to submit something to the arXiv while at the same time submitting it for formal feedback from elsewhere. Unless there is a reason to hurry with the publication, it would make more sense to get that feedback so it can be incorporated before submitting (no point in ending up with more versions than necessary on arXiv).

Comment: Some thoughts on why it might be an OK move: (1) a review paper that is worth sharing with the community but not publishing; (2) research on an existing dataset; (3) could be part of multiple-semester or capstone project (re: extended effort)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft "while at the same time submitting it for formal feedback" - submitting to a journal falls under that category.

Comment: "The only type of work that’s suitable for submitting to arXiv is a research paper."  That's not entirely true - people can and do post on arXiv things like surveys, lecture notes, expository papers, and so on.  But I agree that there's not much overlap between papers one might submit for a course assignment, and papers suitable for arXiv.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, I wrote that knowing it was only approximately true, but it’s a very good approximation (I would say 99% accurate for experienced researchers, and essentially 100% accurate from the perspective of a graduate student thinking whether to upload something they wrote to arXiv). Thanks for the added detail though.

Comment: "I have never heard of a student submitting a research paper as a class project to be graded"  This is a bizarre claim.  It is standard practice in the social sciences.

Comment: All this answer really needed was the first sentence.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist that’s interesting (about social sciences). Do you have some link to back up this claim?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist and, just to be precise, by “research paper” I mean original research, e.g., something that can be submitted to a journal and/or become a part of a student’s PhD thesis.

Comment: I've been told that students in my father-in-law's graduate crystallography course regularly published the results of their projects for that course.

Comment: Yes I knew what you meant, and no I do not have a link, and no I never do reference requests on Stack Exchange anyway.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist good that you stand by your principles! I guess I will have to live with not knowing whether what you wrote is true.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeckes, I stand corrected, and edited my answer. I guess this happens in some discipline. Just to satisfy my curiosity, by “published” do you mean in peer-reviewer journals? ArXiv? Both?

Comment: @MarkMeckes: Do you have links to back up this claim?

Comment: I mean in peer-reviewed journals --- this would have been mostly before the arXiv existed, and it was experimental chemistry which even now has no presence on arXiv.  I don't have time for a lot of detective work, but a quick search turns up this probable example: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ic00222a026

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Right, but when submitting to a journal, I expect that it will be a long time before I get any feedback, and there will not have been any reason for me to not ask for feedback in other ways beforehand. In this case, there is (presumably) an explicit expectation that the OP will not have asked for much feedback, since it is a project to be graded, and they can hopefully expect to get feedback within a short timeframe.